# Send image to server retrofit kotlin

Tags: image, kotlin, retrofit, multipart

I need to send image to server using retrofit with kotlin .. I tried to use multipart but the image was null and the request is strange !

What can I do to use multipart with kotlin and retrofit to send image to server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add Multipart tag on your APIInterface function like this

```
@Multipart
@POST(your api url)
suspend fun uploadImage(
@Header("Header") header: String?,
@Part imageFile: MultipartBody.Part
): Response<StatusResponse>
```

And call this function from your activity like this

```
  val imageFile = File(yourImage)
                val requestFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
                    "image/jpg".toMediaTypeOrNull(),
                    imageFile
                )
                val image =
                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", imageFile.name, requestFile)
                apiClient.uploadImage(header,image)
```

Comment: How get (yourImage) ? I get it as URI

Comment: yes, your image is a URI